# Use PowerShell to Create AppPool does not set AppPool Identity

Tags: windows, iis, powershell, application-pool

I am attempting to use PowerShell to create an Application Pool in IIS.  After searching the web, I created the following test script:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$siteName = "TestAppPool"
$userAccountName = "Domain\UserName"
$userAccountPassword = "MyPassword"

if(!(Test-Path ("IIS:\AppPools\" + $siteName)))
{
     $appPool = New-Item ("IIS:\AppPools\" + $siteName)

     #Display Default AppPool Settings
     "AppPool = " + $appPool
     "UserName = " + $appPool.processModel.userName
     "Password = " + $appPool.processModel.password
     "Runtime = " + $appPool.managedRuntimeVersion
     
     $appPool.processModel.userName = $userAccountName
     $appPool.processModel.password = $userAccountPassword
     $appPool.managedRuntimeVersion = "v4.0"
     $appPool | Set-Item

     #Display Updated AppPool Settings
     "AppPool = " +$appPool
     "UserName = " + $appPool.processModel.userName
     "Password = " + $appPool.processModel.password
     "Runtime = " + $appPool.managedRuntimeVersion
}
```

When I run the script, the user name and password are not updated to the values I set.

Here are the results from the two print blocks

```
#Display Default AppPool Settings
AppPool = Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
UserName = 
Password = 
Runtime = v2.0

#Display Updated AppPool Settings
AppPool = Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
UserName = 
Password = 
Runtime = v2.0
```

Looking in IIS, the Application Pool shows the .Net Framework was updated, yet the Identity is still set to ApplicationPoolIdentity.  It should be Domain\UserName.

[image]

I'm an admin on the machine, and I am running PowerShell in Administrator mode.  Any ideas as to what I may be missing to get this to work?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You will need to change the Process Model identity type to accept a user account instead of the default ApplicationPoolIdentity and this can be done as follows:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\TestAppPool -Name processmodel.identityType -Value 3
Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\TestAppPool -Name processmodel.userName -Value Domain\UserName
Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\TestAppPool -Name processmodel.password -Value MyPassword
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I had to use `-Name processmodel.userName` - it appears to be case-sensitive (in Server 2016, at least).

Comment: @user2871239 Thanks, this was the key for me, userName is definitely case sensitive in 2016 and above.

Answer (score 7):

I came across this after needing to set the appPool to `NetworkService` and for anyone else needing to do this, here is the syntax for IIS 7.5 to set your appPool to `NetworkService`

```
$pool = get-item("IIS:\AppPools\YOURAPPPOOLNAME");
$pool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "ProcessModel.IdentityType" -Value 2
```

**Note: In IIS 7.5, `NetworkService` was switched from value 3 to value 2.**

More information about `Process Model` can be found here: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/processmodel

Comment: Thank you for including the link to the documentation... helps identify the "magic numbers"

Answer (score 3):

above never worked for me, this did:

```
import-module webadministration
$pool = Get-Item "IIS:\AppPools\apppoolname"
$pool.processmodel.identityType = 3
$pool.processmodel.username  = "username"
$pool.processmodel.password = "password"
$pool | set-item
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems setting the identity. Finally, I checked to see what it was setting the password to:

```
Get-ItemProperty $appPool -name "processmodel.password"
```

And saw only a partial password. Turns out that I was using double quotes for the password string param, and the password started with '$' which caused it to get parsed as a variable.

I changed the double quotes to single quotes and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my environment, these answers weren't working for me. I am trying to use an MSA as the identity for my app pool. I could run all the commands (@musaab-al-okaidi's answer) without any error in the console, but upon further inspection, no username was associated with the app pool.

I ended up modifying the `applicationHost.config` file directly (make a backup first!) to add the proper identity for the app pool.

For those who don't know, the applicationHost.config can be found in: `c:\Windows32\inetsrv\config`

Within the`applicationHost.config` file, look for your app pool entry, and add a 'username' attribute, like the following:

```
<system.applicationHost>
    <applicationPools>
        <add name="someAppPool" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning">
            <processModel identityType="SpecificUser" userName="domain\username$" idleTimeout="00:00:00" />
        </add>
    </applicationPools>
</system.applicationHost>
```

You can also set the password in similar fashion (since I am using an MSA, there was no need to set the password here, since the MSA is 'managed' in AD and installed on the IIS box).

I also stopped/started the IIS server, just to be sure the new configs were loaded.

Hopefully that helps.